# validate a binary files presence with schematron

Tags: xml, schema, xslt-2.0, saxon, schematron

Id like to use schematron to validate that a file specified in the test document is actually present. The document and file will always reside in the same directory. e.g.:

```
<foo icon="bar.png" />
```

The presence of a file named "bar.png" within the same directory as the document being validated should pass.

My research up to this point leads me to believe this may not even be possible.

I'm using Saxon EE 9.3 though oXygen XML with XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could write an extension function, but getting the location of the document being validated looks seriously out of scope to me, certainly it should be location agnostic.

The process doing the schematron might not have access to that path....

And once you've passed validation, there's no way you can know the file's been disappeared, looks like a lot of work for a very dubious reward to me.

We use NMatrix with C# which is sort of dead. I say we , a colleague who's recently left did most of the work, so those remaining have engaged our cloaking devices...

I think I'd be looking at something simple and doing it an extra 'validation' step.